# How to get a zero matrix with only upper diagonal elements? (The elements of upper diagonal are known)

Tags: python, numpy

I have a given row matrix  and i want it to be elements of upper diagonal on my zero matrix

If i have a matrix `a = [1,2,3]` then i want my output as

```
[[0 1 0 0]
[0 0 2 0]
[0 0 0 3]
[0 0 0 0]]
```

my original code is

```
import numpy as np
N=5
a0=2*np.ones((1,N))
a1=-1*np.ones((1,(N-1)))
A0=np.diag(a0,0)
A1=np.diag(a1,1)
A2=np.diag(a1,-1)
```

The output of A1 is only [-1] when i require is the complete matrix with elements a1 on the upper diagonal

Comment: You're creating a 2d vector @hoppy. Use `a1=-1*np.ones(N-1)`. Otherwise `np.diag` works differently, it *takes* the main diagonal from the fed array

Comment: thanks @yatu, this did the job

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`np.diag`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diag.html) with an offset:

```
a=np.array([1,2,3])
np.diag(a, 1)

array([[0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 2, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 3],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```